# Explain the word пункт?

Tags: перевод

Здравствуйте,

I am using a book that is a little confusing. I have tried the translate machines and got some garbage back so I am asking the Experts.

The word, пункт, what does it refer to?
Could a пункт be a bigger department store or the small stores and outlets one find inside and just outside the subway in Moscow?

An example was request. Enclosing two examples:

> 1) Также есть государственные пункты на некоторых станциях метро.
>
> 2) В Москве и в Санкт-Петербурге есть довольно много обменных пунктов.

Спасибо большое

Comment: Better provide the context. "Пункт" may mean too many things like, say, "point" does. On the matter of "small store / outlet", usually it's "ларёк", "киоск", or just "точка".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**Пункт**" here seems to refer to a [usually small] currency exchange office or branch ("обменный пункт" = "пункт обмена валюты").  You can probably call it "kiosk", but it's probably beefier than, say, a kiosk that sells public transportation tickets.

Comment: Is it wrong to assume smaller stores? Would a department store apply to punkt? What about the word "точка" would it be ok to use that and not be treated badly?

Comment: Yes and no, "punkt" comes from German and means a point.  The word "пункт" can be used in a phrase "destination point" ("пункт назначения"), which can be an entire city...

Comment: Would it be wrong to apply the German meaning about "punkt" and expand it with ("пункт назначения") ?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, sorry.  What context?

Answer (score 4):

пункт = *point* in various senses (but *neither* in geometry, nor punctuation of numbers or words, nor in the phrase *"What's your point?"*, nor the verb/participle "to point")

So it may mean

- a place on the map such as a city or town. Idiom *населенный пункт* means any settlement.
- a point of departure or arrival (cf. also *пункт назначения*)
- a small place where people do some task staying in place (distribute things, exchange currency, collect scrap - *пункт обмена валюты*, *пункт приёма металлолома* and so on)
- a checkpoint or a small police office (*контрольно-пропускной пункт* aka *КПП*, *опорный пункт*)
- an item in a list, a numbered paragraph.